# Trying to retrieve a class in a class using Canopy and F#

Tags: html, f#, canopy-web-testing

I'm trying to use [canopy](https://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/actions.html) to use F# to play a game of Tic Tac Toe [here](http://playtictactoe.org/). The "board" looks like the follow

```
<div class="game">
<div class="board">
<div class="square top left"><div class="x"></div></div>    <--- take note here
<div class="square top"><div></div></div>
<div class="square top right"><div></div></div>
<div class="square left"><div></div></div>
<div class="square"><div></div></div>
<div class="square right"><div class="o"></div></div>       <--- take note here
<div class="square bottom left"><div></div></div>
<div class="square bottom"><div></div></div>
<div class="square bottom right"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

When you click to either place an X or an O it'll change `<div>` to `<div class="o">` I'm trying to retrieve the state of the board but it doesn't work because say I do the simplest thing for example

```
let state = elements |> ".square"
```

This will return 9 elements... but it doesn't return that the sub div is an x or not since "x" is an attribute not a value.

So essentially my question is. How do I retrieve that a certain position contains an X or O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I have not looked at SO in a long time!

This one is kind of tricky, if you own the code you can make your life a little easier by changing it from

```
<div class="square top left">
to  
<div class="square top-left">
```

If not, you will need to probably create 9 selectors, one for each position on the board.

Something like this, not tested:

```
let topLeft = ".square.top.left"
let topCenter = ".square.top:not(.left,.right)"
let topRight = ".square.top.right"
let middleLeft =".square.left:not(.top,.bottom)"
etc
```

Then you to check if those square has an X or an O

```
let hasX square = 
  let result = someElement <| sprintf "%s .x" square
  match result with
  | None    -> false
  | Some(_) -> true

and one for hasO
```

then you can do

```
if hasX topLeft then
  //whatever
```